# How do I get 5 rows from the end of my sheet in Google Sheets using Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet named 'Members' in my google sheets doc, from which I want to get the last 5 rows' data in JSON format using Google Apps Script. I only have two columns in my sheet, so the JSON won't be big.

I found out apps script has a getlastrow() function, which returns the last row of the sheet - will this function help me in my case? I am new to google apps script so I am unsure where to begin... How do I do this? Please guide... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About `I want to get the last 5 rows' data in JSON format using Google Apps Script.`, if your expected JSON format is like `[{"header1": "value1", "header2": "value2"},,,]`, how about the following sample script.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet including "Members" sheet. And, please run this function. By this, you can see the last 5 rows and the array including JSON data for each row in the log.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Members"; // Please set the sheet name.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const [header, ...values] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  const last5Rows = values.slice(-5); // This is last 5 rows.
  console.log(last5Rows); // You can see this value in the log.

  const obj = last5Rows.map(r => header.reduce((o, h, j) => (o[h] = r[j], o), {})); // This is an array including JSON data of each row.
  console.log(obj); // You can see this value in the log.
}
```

- When this script is run, the values are retrieved from "Members" sheet. And, the last 5 rows are retrieved, and an array including JSON data for each row is created.

#### Note:

- Unfortunately, I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand `JSON format` from your question. So, if the output result of above sample script was not your expected value, can you provide the sample input and output values? By this, I would like to modify the script.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: Thanks, @Tanaike! I just had a couple of questions - 
1) An online JSON validator shows that the output JSON is not valid due to missing quotes on header names : currently the JSON looks like - `[{Image: 'data', Caption: 'data'}]`. Whereas it should look like - `[{"Image":"data", "Caption":"data"}]`. The header names need double quotes, and their values also need double quotes instead of singles. How to do this?
2) Also what if I want to print the `obj` variable on screen? Would `return ContentService.createTextOutput("text here");` help to print an object as well? Kindly guide... Thanks! :)

Comment: @Sonal Thank you for replying. About your new 2nd question of `1) An online JSON validator shows that the output JSON is not valid due to missing quotes on header names : currently the JSON looks like - [{Image: 'data', Caption: 'data'}]. Whereas it should look like - [{"Image":"data", "Caption":"data"}]. The header names need double quotes, and their values also need double quotes instead of singles. How to do this?`, in this case, please use `JSON.stringify` like `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));`.

Comment: @Sonal About your new 3rd question of `2) Also what if I want to print the obj variable on screen? Would return ContentService.createTextOutput("text here"); help to print an object as well?`, unfortunately, I cannot understand your 3rd question. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Because I cannot resolve your all questions. I think that I have to study English s more.

Comment: @Sonal By the way, I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I couldn't understand whether the 1st question you posted was resolved. Can I ask you about it?

Comment: Hi, @Tanaike, thanks a lot for replying - please do not worry, I totally understand everything :) Firstly I apologize for my delayed reply, I was a bit caught up. Your suggestion `JSON.stringify()` works perfectly and solved my first question. Let me elaborate the second one - I wanted to display the formatted JSON into my web browser's screen using `return contentservice.createtextoutput()` command - I tried to do it myself, and it worked for me. So, I'm all done now. Thanks a lot again! Have a great day :)

Comment: @Sonal Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.